# Plotting the results from a matrix ODE

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to plot the results from the following command:

```
m={{30,64,23},{-11,-23,-9},{6,15,4}}

DSolve[{y1'[x], y2'[x],y3'[x]} == m.{y1[x], y2[x],y3[x]}, {y1[x], y2[x],y3[x]}, x]
```

But since there are no initial conditions, the result is a unknown coefficient-based set of functions. I would like to plot $ g(t)=log(y1(t)^2+y2(t)^2+y3(t)^2)$ along the solution curve which goes through $y=(1,1,1)$ and also find it's slope. The slope is just $g'(t)$, so that should work, but the plotting through that point is not easy.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Directly solving the system with the i.c.s should work… Did you ask this because you found something like `DSolve[{{y1'[x], y2'[x], y2'[x]} == m . {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x]}, {y1[0], y2[0], y3[0]} == {1, 1, 1}}, {y1[x], y2[x], y3[x]}, x]` doesn't work i.e. you didn't notice the typo in `{y1'[x], y2'[x], y2'[x]}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(* solve *)
m={{30,64,23},{-11,-23,-9},{6,15,4}};
sol=First[DSolve[{{y1'[x],y2'[x],y3'[x]}==m.{y1[x],y2[x],y3[x]},
    y1[0]==1,y2[0]==1,y3[0]==1},{y1[x],y2[x],y3[x]},x]];

(* g and its slope *)
g=Log[y1[x]^2+y2[x]^2+y3[x]^2]/.sol//Simplify;
slope=D[g,x];

(* plot *)
Plot[{g,slope},{x,0,4},PlotLegends->{"g","slope"},AxesLabel->{"x"}]
```

[image]